# Sending the Pickerview data into URL

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I got my Project ID : 12 when selecting the Data from Picker view. Now my problem is I want to send that 12 (project ID) to NSURL so that my tasks gets loaded respectively when changing the project. Here is my code below:

ViewDidload :

```
NSString *nsTaskurllocal = @"http://xxxx/xxx/";
    NSString *projectsLabel = [self.lblProjects text];
    NSString *aString = [nsTaskurllocal stringByAppendingString:projectsLabel];
    NSLog(@"aString : %@", aString);
    NSString *temp = [aString stringByAppendingString:@"/"];

    int usrid = 313;
    NSString *usridstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", usrid];
    NSString *finalurl = [usridstring stringByAppendingString:temp];
    NSURL *nstaskurl = [NSURL URLWithString:finalurl];
     NSLog(@"nstaskurl : %@", nstaskurl);

    NSData *nstaskpostData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *nstaskpostLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[nstaskpostData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *nstaskrequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:nstaskurl];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:nstaskpostLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/projectpicker" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/jsonArray" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:nstaskpostData];


    NSError *nstaskerror = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *nstaskresponse = nil;
    NSData *nstaskurlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:nstaskrequest returningResponse:&nstaskresponse error:&nstaskerror];
    NSURLRequest *nstaskurlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nstaskurl
                                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                            timeoutInterval:30];


    // Make synchronous request
    nstaskurlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:nstaskurlRequest
                                    returningResponse:&nstaskresponse
                                                error:&nstaskerror];
    if ([nstaskresponse statusCode] >= 200 && [nstaskresponse statusCode] < 300)
    {
        NSString *nstaskresponseData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:nstaskurlData
                                                                 options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&nstaskerror];

        NSArray *nstaskentries = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[nstaskresponseData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                           options:0 error:&nstaskerror];
        if(!nstaskentries)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error : %@", nstaskerror);
        }
        else{

            for (NSDictionary *nstaskentry in nstaskentries) {
                 taskID = [nstaskentries valueForKey:@"ID_TASK"];
                taskNames = [nstaskentries valueForKey:@"TASk_NAME"];

                //NSLog(@"Error : %@", taskNames); //log to see the result in console // by Kiran
            }

            _projectpicker.delegate = self;
            _projectpicker.dataSource = self;
        }

    }       else {

    }

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    NSNumber *myProjectArrayString = [projID objectAtIndex:row];
    //NSNumber *myTaskArrayString = [taskID objectAtIndex:row];
    //NSLog(@"%@",myArrayString);
    //NSLog(@"%@",myTaskArrayString);
    lblProjects.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",myProjectArrayString];
    //lblProjects.hidden = YES;
    lblTasks.text = [taskNames objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]];
    //lblTasks.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myTaskArrayString];
    lblSubTasks.text = [subtaskNames objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:2]];
}
```

lblProjects.text has Project ID :12 so I need to pass this 12 to my aString so that I can append and pass this to NSURL
Thnaks

Comment: do you want to send information (12) in body of service right?

Comment: that 12 is Dynamic ID. Here the user selects a data from picker view and based on the selection the ID is loading into the label and that needs to be sent to NSURL so that it can load the Tasks respectively wit Projects selection..

Comment: can you show me how your final urls looks like. i guess http://xxxx/xxx/userID/projectId... please let me know

Comment: Yes that is the Exact URL http://xxxx/xxxx/projectID/userID

Comment: please take a look at my answer if you get any issue let me know

Answer (score 0):

try to split the string by dividing for component, so [splitArray lastObject] is your "12"

```
NSString *nsTaskurllocal = @"http://xxxx/xxx/";
NSString *projectsLabel = @"Project ID :12";
NSArray *splitArray = [projectsLabel componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
NSString *aString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", nsTaskurllocal, [splitArray lastObject]];
```

aString should be `http://xxxx/xxx/12` now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i hope this will help, If you get any issue let me know

```
-(void)postMethod   
{   
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:******"];
NSString *userIDString=@"131";
NSString *productIDString=@"12";
NSString * productIdString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",userIDString,productIDString];
NSData* postData= [productIdString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *decode = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:postData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",decode);
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:string] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:postData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString*s11=   [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Comment: Thank you Charan for Quick Response, When trying with the above code I was Getting
 NSString * productIdString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[self.lblProjects text],usrid];
 NSLog(@"aString : %@", productIdString);

http://xxxx/xxxx/Label/313

Comment: it working for me try productId statically check my answer once.. now we are decoding the string to check whether we are sending correctly or not. check it and let me know